# kineticjs font is too thick

Tags: fonts, kineticjs

I have the following code and I keep getting fonts that are really bold, but I'm not asking for that.

```
var myText = new Kinetic.Text({
            x: RoundOneX +.5,
            y: RoundOneY+2.5,
            text: thisname,
            fontSize: "8pt",
            fontFamily: 'r',
            width: 70,
            stroke: 'black',
            align: 'center'
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your width:70 is *way* too thick for your tiny fontSize:"8pt"**

Your code will draw the outline of your text (inside fill will be empty).

Try this configuration and adjust from there:

```
var myText = new Kinetic.Text({
        x: RoundOneX +.5,
        y: RoundOneY+2.5,
        text: thisname,
        fontSize: "12pt",
        fontFamily: 'arial',
        fill: 'black',
        align: 'center'
    });
```